# Is there any technical reason why we now should put third-party modules in the [docroot]/modules folder?

Tags: 8

Is there any technical reason why we now should put third-party modules in the [docroot]/modules folder? It seems like an odd inconsistency that common third-party modules go there, while multisite-specific modules go in the traditional /sites/[site]/modules folder. It appears that creating a sites/all/modules folder still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technical? Not really, it isn't faster or anything like that.

It's basically about Developer/User Experience. It's 2 clicks less to go there and find a module.

Also, there multiple issues to either drop multisite entirely (although most people disagree with that) or not exposing it by default and just have a settings/settings.php by default.

- [Move settings.php to /settings directory, fold sites.php into settings.php](https://www.drupal.org/node/1757536)
- [Discuss whether to deprecate multisite for removal in 9.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/2306013)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the reasoning was that it was confusing for people new to the system to have a modules folder in the base directory that you're not supposed to touch at all, and the modules folder you're supposed to use is buried in sites/all/modules.

Personally, I think it makes sense to move all the core files to the core folder and using the modules and themes folders for custom and contributed modules.